# Querying the Mongo DB database to get the average age of students

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I am looking for the answer to appear without id null to look like the following

<"Average": 33>
but mine is appearing as below

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) in your aggregation pipeline and exclude `_id`.

P.g. `[{$group{...}},{ $project: { "_id":0 } }]`

Comment: Thank you when i enter the query the following result appears

Comment: Thank you when i enter the query i get a syntax error db.docs.aggregate([{$group{..}, {$project:{"_id":0}}, "Average":{$avg:"$details.age"}]);

Comment: You are supposed to replace the '..' dots (which I wanted to be '...', now fixed) with your previous group JSON.